# Getting a list of all programs that are using java on Windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7

we are trying to install a newer version of java but are not able to because there is a program that is using a previous version. we dont know what that program is. is there a way to get a list of prgrams that are currently using java?

Comment: How do you know that there is another program that is using it?

Comment: What, in the whole world? Or just on your phone? Please provide some details!

Comment: @Cylindric we don't know this for sure but we arent able to install a newer version

Comment: Why not?? Give the error you're getting.  Or the symptoms.  There are many reasons a Java install might fail.  We can't see your screen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way which would cover majority of cases is this:
1. search for all files with the extension JAR
2. search for all files called java.exe file - usually programs which require java have the jre installed in their directory structure

Answer (score 3):

If you're using windows, then download [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653). This will give you access to all of the processes currently running, along with their children. It gives much more detailed information than Task Manager.